# Prove $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)... (1+a_n) \geq 2^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, solution-verification

> > Prove $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)... (1+a_n) \geq 2^n$ given $ a_1 * a_2 * a_3 ... * a_n=1 $, given $a_1, a_2... a_n$ are all positive

My approach to this question:

Applying AM$\geq$GM alone on $a_1,a_2,a_3... a_n$ we get

$ \dfrac{a_1+a_2+a_3 ... +a_n}{n} \geq ((a_1*a_2*..*a_n)^\frac{1}{n}  $

Since right side is equal to one

$ a_1+a_2+a_3 ... +a_n \geq n $

Now again applying AM $\geq$ GM on $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)..(1+a_n)$

$ \dfrac{(1+a_1)+(1+a_2)+(1+a_3)+...+(1+a_n)}{n} \geq ((1+a_1)(1+a_2)..(1+a_n))^\frac{1}{n} $

Since $1$ is repeated n times and $a_1+a_2+a_3... +a_n$ minimum value is n as shown before

$ \dfrac{n+n}{n} \geq ((1+a_1)(1+a_2)..(1+a_n))^\frac{1}{n} $

$ 2^n \geq (1+a_1)(1+a_2)..(1+a_n) $

Why am I getting reversed equation? Can anyone help me in spotting my mistake?

Comment: I assume that $a_k\geq0$, without which the inquality may be false. Then use $1+a_k\geq 2\sqrt{a_k}$, and then multiply them.

Comment: @Feng I know other methods to solve this question but can you tell what is wrong in this method?

Comment: Your mistake is that you use $(1+a_1)+(1+a_2)+(1+a_3)+...+(1+a_n)\leq n+n$, but you have proven $(1+a_1)+(1+a_2)+(1+a_3)+...+(1+a_n)\geq n+n$.

Comment: If you want your solution verified, while knowing that your question is a duplicate, then please tag your question as a [tag:solution-verification] question. This will not prevent duplicate closure but allows users to focus on your attempt rather than the underlying question.

Comment: "Since right side is equal to one" - the right hand side is wrong in this instance of AM-GM.

Comment: @lisyarus Sorry my bad

Comment: The comment by @Desperado is effectively the answer, just looking at it in a slightly different manner.  You have, more generally, an inequality of the form $f(\mathbf{a}) \leq g(\mathbf{a})$.  Knowing the minimum of $g(\mathbf{a})$ is $2$ doesn't allow us to make an upper limit for $f(\mathbf{a})$.  The most common time you can do this type of step is when the two functions use different independent variables (e.g. $f(\mathbf{a}) \leq g(\mathbf{b})$ with rectangular domain $(\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}) \in A\times B$), but this isn't the case here.

Comment: The comment of @SarveshRavichandranIyer brings up an interesting point that I was unaware of.  Strictly speaking your posting, which I consider to be of high quality, is **not** a *please-verify-my-solution* posting, but is instead a *where-did-I-go-wrong* posting.  Apparently, such questions are also supposed to be tagged solution-verification questions.  This seems bizarre to me, because it is obvious, to any reviewer reading your question, that you are asking : where-did-I-go-wrong?  However, perhaps the comment of SarveshRavichandranIyer still pertains, and I was simply unaware of this.

Comment: There is an underlying issue.  There is no quality control on the responses of MathSE reviewers, even when the posting is of an obviously high quality, as your posting is.  What this means is that often, reviewers will negligently categorize a *where-did-I-go-wrong* posting, such as yours, as a duplicate question, despite the fact that such categorization is ridiculous.  Falsely tagging your posting as a solution-verification posting may deter such ridiculous behavior on the part of MathSE reviewers.

Comment: @user2661923 This is NOT falsely tagged as solution-verification. It is done very much with the idea that it is a solution verification. "I just wanted to know what is wrong with my method" is straight-up solution-verification, and there is an answer below that would have been okay unless the question was answered. Turns out, it has been rejected. Note that I've actually voted up this question. I still maintain, this *is* a "please-verify-my-solution" posting. It is of high quality, I never debated that.

Comment: As for the question of duplication, [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34221/-verification-questions-and-duplicates-proposal-for-discussion) spoke about it. If the underlying question whose solution is being verified is a duplicate, then at least some users think that warrants dupe closure. That population was being represented by me in that comment, because I've been part of it. Such a dupe closure will in no way reflect on the quality of the post : this one is good.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I interpret the phrase *solution-verification* to indicate that the OP is posting a solution that is (perhaps) different from the usual solution and wants to know if the posted solution is valid.  Such a situation is distinct from *where-did-I-go-wrong*.  It may well be that a significant number of experienced MathSE reviewers have chosen to blur the distinction, for their own reasons.  However, to the outside world, where-did-I-go-wrong is not the same as *is-my-proof-valid*.  ...see next comment

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer As for the shared (emperor-new-clothes) pretense that a solution-verification question or a *where-did-i-go-wrong* question is a duplicate, if the underlying question is a duplicate, that is nothing more than a convenient shared pretense.  To the rational world, that is not a duplicate, despite the fact that the underlying question is a duplicate.  Typically, each solution-verification or where-did-I-go-wrong posting is distinct, regardless of whether the distinction is expedient to recognize.  I am trying very hard to be courteous, so I will stop writing now.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm sorry that I have stretched your courtesy : I have no problem with your opinions because you defend them well enough, and therefore act on them reasonably. Of course I blur the distinction between the two interpretations, and that's based on experience. Whether an SV , or a "where I went wrong?" request, answerers must still look at the proof in detail. Duplicate closure is for site organization, as the meta post argues. If these conflict heavily with how you moderate, then I still don't see a problem : people disagree, and we can do so courteously.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the AM-GM inequality for:-

1. For 1 and $a_{1}$:-
   $$\frac{a_{1}+1}{2} \geq √{a_{1}}$$
2. For 1 and $a_{2}$:-
   $$\frac{a_{2}+1}{2} \geq √{a_{2}}$$
   Continuing like this till $a_{n}$:-
   $$\frac{a_{n}+1}{2} \geq √{a_{n}}$$
   Combining all the inequations  and the fact the the product of all $a_{i}$ is equal to 1, we get:-
   $$\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_{k}+1}{2} \geq 1$$
   $$\prod_{k=1}^{n} {a_{k}+1} \geq 2^{n}$$

Comment: I know how to solve this question by other methods, they are available on google. I just wanted to know what is wrong with my method